# "Incorrect syntax near '.'." when using "insert into select" statement

Tags: vb.net

Hello friends i came here waiting for your help, i wan reading similar error in this site but nothing useful for me, i am using "insert into select" statement but something is wrong i can't find the mistake, i think is problem with aliases of the tables but if i write *tableName.ColumName* i get the same error i am almost crazy, 
here is my Code:

```
Dim sqlventa As New SqlCommand
        Form2.conexionLocal.Open()
        Try
            sqlventa.CommandText = ("Insert into Ventas (Codigo_Consejera, Venta_Acumulada)" _
                           & "select T0.Codigo_Consejera, SUM(T1.Precio_Articulo) as ""Venta_Acumulada""" _
                           & "From Transacciones as T0 inner join Detalle as T1" _
                           & "On T0.Pedido_numero = T1.Pedido_numero" _
                           & "Where month(T0.Fecha) = '" & mes & "'and year(T0.Fecha)='" & year & "' Group by T0.Codigo_Consejera")
            sqlventa.Connection = Form2.conexionLocal
            sqlventa.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("ventas acumuladas calculadas con exito")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            Form2.conexionLocal.Close()
        End Try
```

Thanks

Comment: Print out the generated text in `sqlventa.CommandText` and include it in the question.

Comment: SQL parameters prevent this and many many worse problems.

Answer (score 1):

When you are building the SQL, your lines neither end with, nor egin with a space, so they will run together:

`Insert into Ventas (Codigo_Consejera, Venta_Acumulada)select T0.Codigo_Consejera, SUM(T1.Precio_Articulo) as "Venta_Acumulada"From Transacciones as T0 inner join Detalle as T1On T0.Pedido_numero = T1.Pedido_numeroWhere month(T0.Fecha) =`etc

so you have `T1On` was the alias of Detalle and no `ON` for your inner join.

to fix, end each line of the string with a space:

```
 sqlventa.CommandText = ("Insert into Ventas (Codigo_Consejera, Venta_Acumulada) " _
 '                                                                   space here ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey i really thanks everyone who give me an answer because i can update my Windows application, if  you don't help me maybe i were killed my self jejeje, i haven't word to explain how many thanks i give you all my friends and teachers of Stackoverflow.com!!

my error was no have blank spaces on my statement and on the other section of my code i was using an "insert into select" but i have to use "Update TABLE A Set A.colum1=B.Colum1 From Table B Inner Join Table A" statement.